# App running under SBT doesn't find a class from Classpath jar

Tags: scala, sbt, jnr

I have a Scala project using sbt. It runs perfectly well under Eclipse, however, trying to run it under sbt (`sbt 'run mount 1440'` — including the parameters I need) leads to a `ClassNotFoundException` — it can not find `jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureProxy` class. However, running `sbt 'last run'` shows me that `jnr-ffi-2.0.3.jar` file (which includes the said class) is actually included in the classpath. Any suggestions on what's happening?

Sources available on github: https://github.com/FileJunkie/vkfs

Comment: You should include the relevant bits of your code here, so it is useful to other visitors who may encounter a similar issue in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build sbt is invalid.

**First**, you need to have empty lines between the `libraryDependecy`s.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "vkfs",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
  )

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.serceman" % "jnr-fuse" % "0.1"
```

**Second**, the dependency "com.github.serceman" can not be resolved. This means either that

- you installed the dependency manually to your Ivy-repository at `.ivy` **or**
- you have not specified a correct resolver ( see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html )

**So in summary**, it seems that Eclipse does something automatically, so your program runs. When it comes to your `build.sbt` it is not valid (empty lines missing) and does not resolve dependencies properly. *I wonder*, how you could start via `sbt 'run mount 1440'` at all.

After correcting the empty lines and running sbt 'run mount 1440' I obtain

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to vkfs (in build file:/home/.../IdeaProjects/vkfs/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/.../IdeaProjects/vkfs/}root...
[info] Resolving com.github.serceman#jnr-fuse;0.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.github.serceman#jnr-fuse;0.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/.../.ivy2/local/com.github.serceman/jnr-fuse/0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/serceman/jnr-fuse/0.1/jnr-fuse-0.1.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.serceman#jnr-fuse;0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.serceman#jnr-fuse;0.1: not found
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
[ ... truncated ... ]
```

### Edit (concerning dependency from jcenter)

Add the following line to your build.sbt (remember extra empty line)

```
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo
```

to add jcenter to your resolver list.

### Edit 2

Resolver.jcenterRepo is not available in SBT 0.13.5, thus

```
resolvers += "jcenter" at "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
```

is required.

**After successful compilation** and run the relevant error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnr/ffi/provider/jffi/NativeClosureProxy
at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureProxy.newProxyFactory(NativeClosureProxy.java:220)
```

### Final result

The library "com.github.serceman" in v 0.1 seems to be problematic, as it can not properly instantiate some class via reflection.

### Solution

Problem solved by adding `fork in run := true` to `build.sbt`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the lack of empty lines between `libraryDependencies` lines, but it changed nothing.


As for `jnr-fuse`, it is available from jcenter repository (in the manual you posted a link to it is said that this repo is available by default), and my sbt successfully resolved this dependency after I cleaned up the cache.


The `ClassNotFoundException` which I mentioned is only reachable in runtime, so since jnr-fuse isn't resolvable on your machine, you could not reach that point where I encounter this exception.

Comment: No, not true. The repo jcenter is not added by default. Instead it is a predefined variable as doc states `Resolver.jcenterRepo`. Will edit my post ...

Comment: Hm. I wonder why does my sbt resolve this dependency at all then. However, adding `resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo` to `build.sbt`, once again, changes nothing for me.

Comment: How are you starting sbt? Just start sbt via `sbt` from bash/shell and call then `run mount 1440` in interactive sbt console.

Comment: Running `sbt 'run mount 1440'` and using the way you described leads to the same results - no dependency issues, all necessary file are in classpath (checking with `last run` command), including `jnr-ffi-2.0.3.jar`, and this the exact file which contains the class which can't be found under sbt.

Comment: See my edit! Problem is a bad library "com.github.serceman". Contact the author of the lib, as it has nothing to do with SBT and build configuration.

Comment: Why it runs under Eclipse is still unclear. How have you added it under eclipse? (I mean installation of the lib).

Comment: No, I just used sbt-eclipse plugin to generate eclipse project.

Thank you for you time, will contact the library author.

Comment: 1. Do not hesitate to "reward" the time effort ;) 2. If it really has **run successfully with Eclipse**, this means there is a solution. So maybe Eclipse provides some libraries that are expected for the serceman lib to run. Try to clarify, what the library expects.